# How to url rewrite in nodejs and receive values on server end

Tags: node.js, express

i want to rewrite the url like this

```
http://localhost:3000/page?N1=568ff78634da
```

and receive value on the server end

```
app.get('/page', function(req, res){
   var x=req.body.N1;
   //do something with the value
});
```

my server is something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
var assert = require('assert');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var session = require("express-session");
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
users = [];
connections = [];
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(session({resave: false, saveUninitialized: true, secret:'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

using this way i am not able to receive values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is get request in get request the data is in query so write this

```
 var someData=request.query.data;
```

in ur case

```
      var someData=request.query.N1;
```

Comment: Or, in this case, `req.query.N1`

Comment: ys try this . it should be

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parameters using the query object, contained within the request e.g.

```
app.get('/page', function(req, res) {
    var x = req.query.N1;
    console.log('x = ' + x);
});
```